# CSS transform doesn't work on Firefox, works on Chrome

Tags: css, cross-browser

http://codepen.io/cory/pen/dILyo

Ugly aqua marine blue circles appear around the borders of the element when viewed on Firefox.

The proper outlook can be seen when viewed on Chrome.

Any ideas how to fix the borders? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the -moz prefix. [Firefox no longer needs that.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation#Browser_compatibility) Also, make sure you make the unprefixed property last in the list.

Comment: I did what you suggested but it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the webkit prefix in the @keyframe property. So use

```
@keyframe
```

and not

```
@-webkit-keyframes
```

because Firefox is not a WebKit browser. More about the keyframes in Firefox:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes

Comment: Fixing the proper keyframes syntax does not fix the blue circles, I've already tried that.